# Bootstrap datepicker refresh/update after first selection

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using bootstrap-datepicker inline mode on a form like this.
Code from the form

```
 <div id="frmdate" data-date=""></div>
```

And and updating the data-date value with jquery ajax returned date from server.

On datepicker date selection we write the value to a hidden input..

```
<input type="hidden" name="ttsasssd" id="ttsasssd">
```

Datpicker code..

The `strtdatedump` variable is the date received from ajax. I write to the "data-date" value on each form submission. To set the new date for datepicker.

```
$("#frmdate").attr("data-date", strtdatedump);
$("#frmdate").datepicker({format: "yyyy/mm/dd"});
$("#frmdate").on('changeDate', function(){
$("#ttsasssd").val(
    $("#frmdate").datepicker('getFormattedDate')
   );
});
```

I tried to use the datepickers update() method to update the datepickers but it is not showing the current set dates.

```
$("#frmdate").datepicker('update');
```

How do I update the datepicker after each form submission ?

Edit 1

How I fetch the new dates,

Editing the question because I can not write comments,  I am fetching the new dates with ajax. I tried to store the new ajax send date in a variable and add that in datepicker but it does not work. What I am doing wrong ???

```
$("#getAddForm").click(function(event){
  $.ajax({
    url: "/top-thirty-assamese/getdate/",
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data){
      if(data !== "")
      {
          var strtdatedump = data.start;
          $("#frmdate").attr("data-date", strtdatedump);
           $("#frmdate").datepicker('update', strtdatedump);
           $("#frmdate").on('changeDate', function(){
              $("#ttsasssd").val(
                  $("#frmdate").datepicker('getFormattedDate')
                );
           });
```

Answer (score 6):

You can call the update on the datpicker directly with the new value for date (I always do this way and it works):

```
$("#frmdate").datepicker('update', "2015/09/39");
```